# Combine Splunk Rex Queries

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I am looking to combine and manipulate two extracted fields from separate logging instances. I am using the `rex` command to do the extraction.

However, from reading documentation it appears it's not possible to combine to separate rex commands that will match different lines.

For example:

Say I have this line logged: `Timestamp Caller foo bar <DATA> blah blah`. Using rex I can grab the `<DATA>` field as simple as `rex field=log "foo bar (?<DATA>\d{1,6}).*`. (Note it is numeric data).

Now I have another line logged as `Timestamp Caller baz qux <DATA2> blah blah`. Again, I can grab `<DATA2>` as `rex field=log "baz qux (?<DATA2>\d{1,6}).*`.

The problem is there is a relationship between `<DATA>` and `<DATA2>` that I'd like to quantify.

How can I run a query that will capture both data points that appear in separate logging lines?

Note: the related `How can I combine 2 queries in Splunk` questions aren't relevant as the data in those questions either appears in the same line or they aren't using `rex` explicitly.

Comment: What relationship are you trying to quantify?  After you have the data points can you just use a where or something to get what you want?  The other thing that I do a lot is run a transaction to group the events and then do the rex on that.  If you can describe what you want to do it would help.

Answer (score 1):

Most Splunk commands operate on a single event at a time.  There is no way to have a single `rex` command process more than one event. (Commands that operate on multiple events are aggregating commands like `stats`).

Comment: Is there an alternative you would suggest?

Comment: Use separate `rex` commands for each field you wish to extract.  Once you have the fields extracted then you may be able to correlate the events using the relationship between them.